# How do I prevent from accidental clicking on adsense ads on my own site?

Tags: google-adsense, google-adsense-policies

I browse my sites many times for testing, adding content and again testing, etc.

How do I prevent from accidental clicking on your own ads?

Is it OK to use ad blocker?

Comment: Use the [The Google Publisher Toolbar](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/2411951), among other things it provides: `The ability to “test click” on ad overlays without those clicks being counted towards ad spam.`